# Bluetooth headset auto connect with PulseAudio

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, audio, bluetooth, pulse-audio

Lubuntu 18.04.4 on acer c720
PulseAudio does not do automatic switch to either of my bluetooth headsets when I switch them on.

My ~/.config/pulse/default.pa contains the lines

```
### Use hot-plugged devices like Bluetooth or USB automatically (LP: #1702794)
.ifexists module-switch-on-connect.so
load-module module-switch-on-connect
.endif
```

and I have the file

```
/usr/lib/pulse-11.1/modules/module-switch-on-connect.so
```

but it does not switch to any of my bluetooth headsets when I turn them on, I have to effect the switch with the bluetooth applet menu "Recent Connections'

If I try

```
~ $  pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

I assume that may be because the config file already has done so.